# JAX Webservice not working in CodenameOne project

Tags: java, web-services, codenameone

I created a simple web service that is running fine:
Interface:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface HelloService {
@WebMethod
    void sayHello();
}
```

Implemented service:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "mypackage.HelloService")
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService {
@Override
public void sayHello() {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
}
```

Publisher:

```
public class HelloServicePublisher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/hello", new HelloServiceImpl ());
    }
}
```

when I create a normal JAVA project, with the following client code, it works perfectly:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/hello?wsdl");

        // 1st argument service URI, refer to wsdl document above
        // 2nd argument is service name, refer to wsdl document above
        QName qname = new QName("http://server/", "HelloServiceImplService");
        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
        HelloService server = service.getPort(HelloService.class);
        server.sayHello();
    }
}
```

This compiles and runs fine. When I copy the VERY SAME client code into a plain new CN1 project, I get a null point exception at the service.getPort() call:

```
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getPortTypeName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getPortTypeName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Unknown Source)
```

So the question is: what on earth is different when creating a CN1 project compared to a normal Java project? It does have nothing to do with the code, as this obviously works. 
Appreciate any tips.

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codename One [doesn't support the full Java API](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html) nor does it support JAX. You can only install libraries supported by Codename One and only use the subset of the JDK mentioned in the [javadocs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/).

The reason for this is explained above but in summary it's a matter of feasibility/size. The full JVM would be well over 50mb closer to 100mb even if we strip out everything that isn't used, by contrast Codename One is close to the efficiency/size of native OS apps clocking at under 5mb.

In the [networking section of the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html) we discuss several approaches for networking including the webservice wizard which generates a servlet you can communicate with from the client. That's both faster (more efficient communication) and has smaller code size.

Comment: Hm, okay. Not exactly what I wanted to hear, but at least a firm statement. I was new to both CN1 and webservices, so first I got my web services going on the server side the way I wanted them to look like. Now I have to rewrite it to whatever CN1 is supporting in terms of web services.

But it was a great experience to learn and ever so slowly I am getting more and more of how all this works. Thanks for all your help!